# Is it possible to temporarily prevent a user account from logging in?

Tags: user-account, encryption, mount, login

I'm trying to setup a system with individually encrypted user home folders, i.e- each user has their own encrypted volume containing their home folder.

The problem is, if I login as a user when that user's home folder isn't mounted, macOS produces no error, it simply treats the login as a new user and creates a fresh new home folder for them where the mounted volume ought to be (`/Users/<shortname>`).

What I ideally would like to do is somehow make it so that the encrypted user account(s) cannot login while the home folder volume isn't mounted.

If it's possible to somehow tie this to the volume being mounted (or not) then that would be ideal (i.e- when mounted the user can login, when it isn't they cannot). Otherwise I'm happy with any kind of command that I can run to disable/re-enable a specific user's ability to login as part of my procedure to mount/unmount the volume (I'll automate this somehow).

I've already tried using the `dscl . create /Users/<shortname> IsHidden 1` command to hide/reveal users but this doesn't seem to take effect right away (i.e- the fast user switching list and main login screen still appear to show the user, possibly doesn't take effect until a restart? This seems like it's no good for anyway).

**NOTE**: Don't worry, not all of the user accounts will have individually encrypted home folders; there will be an admin account on the main system volume as normal, so there's at least one use who can always login.

So, is there a way to temporarily disable a user account (prevent login) on macOS?

Comment: Perhaps change their UID to -1 (nobody)? Note: haven't tried that before; make sure to try it on non-production system.

Comment: I think if you do this as a (system) launch daemon it should load during the booting process, i.e. if it doesn't finish, you won't see the login screen.

Comment: Or, just move the user plist (/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<username>.plist) and restore it? Or point this plist to one on the disk image so that it would be invalid when the disk image is not mounted? Note that this is also unsupported by Apple.

Comment: Sorry, the UID should be -2.

Comment: Just out of the curiosity: Assuming you have FileVault enabled and user accounts have appropriate access rights set (700 on /Users/user), what kind of additional security do you get from encrypting each home folder?

Comment: @nohillside Being individual volumes means greater isolation, and being individually encrypted means no one password can decrypt everything. In my case I'm using ZFS for storing my users, and I find it much easier to work with them as separate datasets per user (individual snapshots, easier backup/recovery etc.), in which case they may as well be individually encrypted (no reason not to). While I *could* mount them all using passwords stored in the system keychain, I'd prefer not to.

Comment: I see the isolation part. But unless I miss something here, you need to mount the user volumes before a user can login. So admin/root has all the passphrases, and while the system is running all the volumes are accessible.

Comment: @nohillside They'd only be accessible while mounted; my intention is that they are unmounted once a user has logged out. But this is becoming discussion, the question is how to prevent logins, the why doesn't really matter.

Comment: Actually, we are getting somewhere :-) How do you mount them *before* the user logs in, if you unmount them once a user logs out?

Comment: @nohillside most likely I'll make a tool to replace the fast user switching menu widget with a background daemon to do the unlock, and have it appear for all users including the guest user so there's always a way to unlock and login. Seems the best way unless Apple ever add pre-login hooks someday. Again though, this isn't helping me to prevent user logins via normal methods (i.e- the main login screen) which is what my question is about.